# ezANOVA: 1) how to omit na data? 2) still getting error message after omitting na data?

Tags: r, dataset, missing-data, na

For my repeated measures analysis using `lme` function I could omit not-available (`na`) data with the command: `na.action=na.omit`.

```
anova_lme_loc<-lme(data=rm1, fixed=Nmin~location*date, random=~1|subject,
                   na.action=na.omit)
```

However, when I try to do the same using the ezANOVA function I got the following notification:

```
anova_ez_loc=ezANOVA(data=rm1, dv=Nmin, wid=subject, within=date, 
                     between=location, na.action=na.omit)
```

> Error in ezANOVA(data = rm1, dv = Nmin, wid = subject, within = date,  : 
>     unused argument(s) (na.action = na.omit)

how can I omit my na data in `ezANOVA`? - solved using:

```
rm1_na <- na.omit(rm1)
```

but now I get the following error:

> anova_ez_loc=ezANOVA(data=rm1_na, dv=Nmin, wid=subject, within=date, between=location)
>
> Warning: Converting "subject" to factor for ANOVA.
>
> Warning: Data is unbalanced (unequal N per group). Make sure you specified a well-considered value for the type argument to ezANOVA().
>
> Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  : 
>     One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data.

Answer (score 2):

`ezANOVA` doesn't handle missing data, as the author outlines in [this reponse](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ez4r/YcDXZiyXRJ0/vuZLMeXL50sJ) to a similar question. You have two options:

1. Remove the missing data manually. The function `complete.cases` may be of help here.
2. Mike Lawrence alternatively suggests checking out `ezMixed` from the same package, which is more complicated but can handle missing data.

To remove the data manually, you would do something like this:

```
rm1.complete <- rm1[complete.cases(rm1),]
```

Then use `rm1.complete` in your analysis.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I actually removed the missing data as you also mentioned but now I get the following notification: > anova_ez_loc=ezANOVA(data=rm1, dv=Nmin, wid=subject, within=date, between=location)
Warning: Converting "subject" to factor for ANOVA.
Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  : 
  One or more cells returned NA when aggregated to a mean. Check your data.     is it possible this is because of "0" values of my response variable?

Comment: Is `rm1` the name of the dataset with the missing data removed? If you run `complete.cases(rm1)`, what do you get?

Comment: > rm1_na <- na.omit(rm1) is what I used, but now I see your point: I should be using rm1_na and not rm1. thank you!! (it is 3.20am here atm; brain=half-asleep)

Comment: anova_ez_loc=ezANOVA(data=rm1_na, dv=Nmin, wid=subject, within=date, between=location)'                                   
Warning: Converting "subject" to factor for ANOVA.
Warning: Data is unbalanced (unequal N per group). Make sure you specified a well-considered value for the type argument to ezANOVA().
Error in ezANOVA_main(data = data, dv = dv, wid = wid, within = within,  : 
  One or more cells is missing data. Try using ezDesign() to check your data.

Comment: -sorry to bother you again but do you know how to solve this ^^^ problem :/ does this mean my data has to be balanced for use in ez?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with `ezANOVA`, so I'm a little out of my depth here. The data doesn't have to be balanced, but maybe you have to specify the design matrix manually? As for why you're still getting the missing data error, I have no idea. Sorry.

Comment: thanks for all your help! do you know if negative respons data could be the reason for this?

Comment: Negative response data shouldn't matter. It's possible that you have an empty cell when you remove all the missing data, which could be causing the problem.

Comment: It's a within subjects ANOVA so it definitely has to be balanced.  Do what it said and look at ezDesign.  That will tell you what subjects are missing cells.  You either have to drop the subjects or impute data.

Comment: Looked at the ezDesign and saw that one 'location' at 'date' 1 has only 1 response variable value (instead of 3), and that that same 'location' at 'date' 2 has 2 out of the 3 response variable values left. This is all due to the removal of not-available data. how can I make it balanced? does it mean I should have 2 values for both 'dates' for that 'location' while the other 'locations' still have 3? Or must all 'locations' have 3 values? is there maybe a way to get the mean of all 3 values for the Rformula to solve this problem; ie each location has 1 mean value, instead of 3 values.

Answer (score 0):

Complement to the answer of @Jonathan Christensen :

When using within-subject factors, `complete.cases` doesn't work because it considers cases row-wise, while you need to get rid of all rows containing the ID of an incomplete case.

Here is a small script that extends `complete.cases` to a custom function called `complete.cases.within` that does everything for you:

```
if(!require(tidyverse)) install.packages("tidyverse"); library(tidyverse) #useful package for clean code

#helper function that returns ALL indices of matches of x in table instead of just the first one
#we need this to get all rows containing the ID of incomplete cases.
matchAll = function(x, table, nomatch=NA_integer_, incomparables=NULL) {
  which(!is.na(match(table, x, nomatch, incomparables)))
}

complete.cases.within = function(data, dv, wid) {
  incomplete = data %>% select(dv) %>% complete.cases() %>% !. #boolean vector containing incomplete rows
  toRemove = data %>% select(wid) %>% filter(incomplete) %>% .[,1] %>% unique() #all IDs containing incomplete rows
  positions = matchAll(toRemove, data[,wid])
  return(if (length(positions)==0) data else data[-positions,]) #drop all rows matching toRemove IDs
}
```